# .NET Framework is getting crashed at irregular intervals

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I have hosted(IIS 7) web application on Windows server 2008 r2. 
This web app worked fine for few days but today it stopped working and an error message displayed like shown below.
[image]
I have opened the Event viewer and got the below shown error message 
**Failed to execute request because App-Domain could not be created.Error: 0x8007000e Not enough** **storage is available to complete this operation.**
***I found many threads with same error but none of them solved this problem***
 1. As it is a Production Server there is no shortage of RAM and disc space etc. 
 2. This web app is running under account operator credentials he has full access to the web app file directory and the same account has Logon as batch privilage.

But i when repaired the >NET Framework 4.0 using the  [Microsoft Repair tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30135) it started working. But the above said error is recurring at irregular intervals(4 hours or 6 hours.) Any help would be appreciated gretly.

[image]

Comment: Soemthing is trashing your Framework. Did you run a virus check or check the hardware components like the hard disk?

Comment: i kept Microsoft Process monitor running for sometime but didnt find much on this issue. if you want that log file i can share it with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft IIS Forum link](http://forums.iis.net/t/1162198.aspx?ASP%20Access%204005%20error%20defining%2032%20bit%20dsn%20on%2064%20bit%20windows) solved my issue. **Enable x32 bit feature** in IIS.
But nowhere we are using any x32 bit component/dll. But this solved our problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Not enough storage is available to complete this operation."

the apppool is actualy recyling it self after a certain amount of hits that is why this happens att diffrent times.

the problem could happen in two cases 1. there is no disc space. 2. you dont have access to create the tempfiles.

So have you actualy checked disc space on the webserver?

And does the user executing your apppool have access to temp folder within .Netframework folder?
If the user is restricted to your appfolder you might have a problem.

Comment: Thnx for your reply.. 1) There is almost 6 GB free space on the server. 2) That user is a Local administrator on that machine.

Comment: how much memory is available , and is it a 32bit or 64bit os?

Comment: windows server 2008 r2 64bit os...Only 6GB is used out of 8GB.

Comment: try adding some more ram , and check if the appool is actualy running in 64bit mode